# Writing an equation in vector form using Mathematica

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to write the following equation using vector notation in Mathematica?

`dp/dt= div(k1 / k2 . grad p)`

Where p is a scalar, k1 is vector, and k2 is a scalar.

Comment: Can you try to be more clear on what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the vector calculus operators in the [`VectorAnalysis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/VectorAnalysis/tutorial/VectorAnalysis.html) package where Laplacian (you did mean Laplacian, right?) is `Laplacian` and gradient is `Grad`. Both have some fancy symbolic replacements I belive. The default Cartesian coordinates are `{Xx,Yy,Zz}`, so this should give what I think you are asking for:

```
<< VectorAnalysis`
D[p[t, Xx, Yy, Zz], t] ==  Laplacian[{k1x, k1y, k1z}.Grad[p[t, Xx, Yy, Zz]]]/k2
```

I'm assuming `k2` is a scalar? The `p^(0,0,0,1)` etc. int the output is Mathematica's way of denoting partial derivatives. If `p` is actually a defined function, they will be calculated.

HTH